# Equivalent to named pipes in Unix for LIFO/Stack structure

Tags: linux, file, unix, data-structures, ipc

I have been looking at all the different types of Unix file: *regular files, directories, device files, symbolic link, doors, socket, named pipes,...*

but I couldn't find a file type that would **behave like a stack/LIFO structure**.

As most of you know, the advantage of FIFO/named pipe over regular files is the following:

from https://askubuntu.com/questions/449132/why-use-a-named-pipe-instead-of-a-file

Almost everything in Linux can be considered a file, but the main difference **between a regular file and a named pipe is that a named pipe is a special instance of a file that has no contents on the filesystem**.

from `man fifo`

> A FIFO special file (a named pipe) is similar to a pipe, except that it is accessed as part of the filesystem. It can be opened by multiple processes for reading or writing. When processes are exchanging data via the FIFO, the kernel passes all data internally without writing it to the filesystem. Thus, the FIFO special file has no contents on the filesystem; the filesystem entry merely serves as a reference point so that processes can access the pipe using a name in the filesystem.
>
> The kernel maintains exactly one pipe object for each FIFO special file that is opened by at least one process. The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed. Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

So I was wondering if this type of file (LIFO/Stack) does actually exist natively in Unix? If it is not the case is there a way to simulate one?

I have been thinking about using `tac <named_pipe>` but I am not sure if it is a good/viable idea?

Is there a better solution?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've always wanted to abuse Bash's `pushd -n item ; dirs +n ; popd -n` as a stack in a script. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks but I do not need to push pop directories, I would like to have a space in memory shared by 2 process that is like a `stack`/`LIFO`

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to implement this, but the first thing you'd have to decide is what are you putting into your stack?  Bytes?  Strings? `int` values?  Then you'd have to decide how to store the items, assuming you implement a kernel driver.  Or even if you store the items - maybe you make the writing process block until the item it's putting on the stack is read? (If the write process doesn't block, you do have to store the item - but then you have to control how many you can store...)  There are a lot of design decisions to be made, and they make a very specific stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Almost everything in Linux can be considered a file, but the main difference between a regular file and a named pipe is that a named pipe is a special instance of a file that has no contents on the filesystem.

A better way of looking at it would be to say that a named pipe is a pipe that appears in the filesystem. It doesn't have content stored on disk, but it's not just an empty inode either -- it has particular behaviors which are specific to pipes.

> So I was wondering if this type of file (LIFO/Stack) does actually exist natively in Unix?

No, it does not exist. Unlike a queue, a stack cannot be treated as a stream; and, in any case, it is not a particularly useful structure in a multiprocess environment. It doesn't make sense to have multiple processes concurrently pushing/popping data from a stack.

> I have been thinking about using `tac <named_pipe>` but I am not sure if it is a good/viable idea?

That won't work. `tac` will read the entire contents of the pipe, and there will be nothing left in the pipe afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed a LIFO is not a regular in/out/err `stream` and I agree that `tac` would empty the whole stack when reading it... any better way to simulate one?

Comment: "It doesn't make sense..." A task scheduler where tasks create sub-tasks is an example of when it's useful. In such a situation a DFS-like execution (arising from LIFO) exploits more temporal locality compared to BFS-like execution (arising from FIFO).

Answer (score 1):

A stack is a perfectly useful and reasonable structure.  It's great for a LIFO task handler such as a program's stack. 
Usually rather than multi process though, I've only had to multi thread such uses via pthreads (and shared memory between the threads helped relieve what would otherwise be IPC) and avoided using an explicit stack by controlling thread creation and termination.  If you needed the threads popping off a shared stack, you could do that as long as you properly blocked with mutex for that and any dependent portions.  (You need to decide if a push and pop are happening at once, whether your pop should wait for the push to finish so you can pop what was just pushed, or wait for the pop to finish so your push happens one tier lower, or it is just first come first serve).

If you insist on multi process rather than single process and multi thread, you could build your own implementation using pipes for IPC and an additional process that manages the stack.  The stack manager would accept push and pop requests via a named pipe and shove popped data onto another named pipe.  You would have to structure your data so that it can be distinguished from push/pop commands or have that pushed data be on a third named pipe.  You would have to be aware of pipe buffers and usage so that you do not cross or split the streams.